# Ошибка Buildozer Kivy Toolchain

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-2.x, kivy

Хочу создать apk файл с помощью Buildozer (kivy), но выдает ошибку при выполнении:

```
[INFO]: Downloading pyjnius from https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius/archive/master.zip
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "/home/kivy/Desktop/ColorS/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 978, in <module>
main()
File "/home/kivy/Desktop/ColorS/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 975, in main
ToolchainCL()
File "/home/kivy/Desktop/ColorS/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 512, in __init__
getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
File "/home/kivy/Desktop/ColorS/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 149, in wrapper_func
build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
File "/home/kivy/Desktop/ColorS/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 193, in build_dist_from_args
build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx)
File "pythonforandroid/build.py", line 551, in build_recipes
File "pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 307, in download_if_necessary
File "pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 353, in download
File "pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 151, in download_file
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 240, in retrieve
fp = self.open(url, data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 208, in open
return getattr(self, name)(url)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 437, in open_https
h.endheaders(data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1013, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 864, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 826, in send
self.connect()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1220, in connect
self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 487, in wrap_socket
ciphers=ciphers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 243, in __init__
self.do_handshake()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 405, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create —dist_name=colorsapp —bootstrap=sdl2 —requirements=kivy —arch armeabi-v7a —copy-libs —color=always —storage-dir=/home/kivy/Desktop/ColorS/.buildozer/android/platform/build
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Понятия не имею, что здесь может быть не так, помогите кто разбирается, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

Нет подключения к сети, очевидно.

Comment: Уже понял,теперь просто " Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create —dist_name=colorsapp —bootstrap=sdl2 —requirements=kivy —arch armeabi-v7a —copy-libs —color=always —storage-dir=/home/kivy/Desktop/ColorS/.buildozer/android/platform/build"

Comment: log_level = 2 в спецификации укажи.

Comment: ,я уже указал - ничего

Comment: log_level=2 выведет полный стек трейс ошибки.

Comment: Я У-К-А-З-А-Л. Я знаю, что log_level 2 выдает полное описание ошибки, но проблема в том, что если ты его поставишь, он все равно будет просить его поставить - это полное описание.

Comment: " Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create —dist_name=colorsapp —bootstrap=sdl2 —requirements=kivy —arch armeabi-v7a —copy-libs —color=always —storage-dir=/home/kivy/Desktop/ColorS/.buildozer/android/platform/build" - вот это - это НЕ log_level=2

Comment: @Xyanight, не стоит ругаться, лучше быть дружелюбным)